# Password active for 12 hours

Tags: php, symfony, password-protection

In order to improve security on a platform that I have to create, I'd like to create a password that is valid for only 12 hours.

I already got my function to create the password :

```
function chaine_aleatoire($nb_car, $chaine = 'azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn123456789')
{
    $nb_lettres = strlen($chaine) - 1;
    $generation = '';
    for($i=0; $i < $nb_car; $i++)
    {
        $pos = mt_rand(0, $nb_lettres);
        $car = $chaine[$pos];
        $generation .= $car;
    }
    return $generation;
}
```

But I actually don't know how to create the expiration. Do I have to add a field in my user entity like "password_expires_at" with a `DateTime`?

Or maybe it's only a simple condition to add in PHP?

Comment: You can add easly an if statement where you compare the current date at the experation date. I think it will be cleaner if you store the date in the same place as your password

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need an additional field on your entity to compare the current time against. Then you have to customize the login process to compare that with the current datetime. I recommend using [a GuardAuthenticator, e.g. like the one described for form logins in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html). In this class you can check the current time against the one saved in your user inside the `checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)` method.